# How do I disable a window?

Tags: python, events, window, tkinter

I am creating a ten question multiple choice quiz in Tkinter / Python. Essentially in the parent window there are 13 buttons - help button, user details, questions 1-10 and an 'End' button. Each button opens up a new window with the question, the options as checkbuttons and radiobuttons and an 'Enter' button which links to a piece of code that will calculate the correct answer and add 1 to the score if condition is true. Once the user has selected the answer and pressed 'Enter' the button will be disabled. However, once the user exits this window they are able to re answer the same question which will obviously result in multiple points being added to the global variable score. How do I disable the question button/window once the user has answered the question? And how do I make the 'Reveal Score' button only activated when all questions have been answered?

I have used a class to define each button and individual classes thereafter for each button so I am not sure if this will cause issues (I am new to Object Orientated). Thanks

I AM AWARE THAT INDENTATION IS NOT CORRECT, IHAD TO FORMAT IT FOR THIS WEBSITE

```
from Tkinter import * #Copied from online examples
import tkMessageBox #Copied from online examples
import Tkinter, Tkconstants, tkFileDialog #Copied from online examples
import Tkinter as tk #Copied from online examples


class Example(tk.Frame):
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    self.question_1_window = None
    self.question_1 = tk.Button(self, text="1", foreground="blue", command=self.show_question_1)
    self.question_1.pack(side="left")

def show_question_1(self):
    '''show the question window; create it if it doesn't exist'''
    if self.question_1_window is None or not self.question_1_window.winfo_exists():
        self.question_1_window = Question_1_Window(self)
    else:
        self.question_1_window.flash()


   class Question_1_Window(tk.Toplevel):
'''A simple instruction window'''
def __init__(self, parent):
    tk.Toplevel.__init__(self, parent)
    self.text = tk.Label(self, width=75, height=4, text = "1) Do you have the time to do at least twenty minutes of prefect duty each week?")
    self.text.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

    question_1_Var = IntVar() #creating a variable to be assigned to the radiobutton

    Yes_1 = Radiobutton(self, text = "Yes", variable = question_1_Var, value=1, height=5, width = 20)
    Yes_1.pack() #creating 'yes' option

    #Here we are assigning values to each option which will be used in the validation

    No_1 = Radiobutton(self, text = "No", variable = question_1_Var, value=2, height=5, width = 20)
    No_1.pack() #creating 'no' option


    def calculate_score_1():
        Enter_1.config(state="disabled")
        if (question_1_Var.get() == 1) and not (question_1_Var.get() == 2):
            print("calculate score has worked") #test lines
            parent.score_per_question[1] = 1
        else:
            print("not worked") #testlines


    Enter_1 = Button(self, text= "Enter", width=10, command = calculate_score_1)
    Enter_1.pack()

def flash(self):
    '''make the window visible, and make it flash temporarily'''

    # make sure the window is visible, in case it got hidden
    self.lift()
    self.deiconify()

    # blink the colors
    self.after(100, lambda: self.text.configure(bg="black", fg="white"))
    self.after(500, lambda: self.text.configure(bg="white", fg="black"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("800x500") #defining the size of the root
root.title("Prefect Quiz") #defining root title
Example(root).pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Kindly show us the relevant code so that we can help you better

Comment: If you don't care about the formatting, why should we care to answer the question? Learn how to use markup on this site. It's really quite simple. First, convert your code to use spaces and tabs. Next, paste your code into your question. Third, highlight the code and then click on the button that looks like `[]` to mark it as code.

Answer (score 0):

If it creates a new window after than you can destroy it.

```
window.destroy()
```

"window" change depending on what you call your tkinter. TK

```
window = tkinter. TK
```

Whatever is before the = is what you replace "window" with.
hope that helped:)

Comment: Destroying a widget is very, very different from disabling it. I really don't think this is what the question is about.